# Get VM name for an instance of Azure web app from REST API or PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I am trying to find a REST API / PowerShell cmdlet to retrieve the VM name(starts with RD) for an instance of Azure web app.

I found out that I can list the process Ids by Instance Id and then get Instance Process with [Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/getinstanceprocess). This object has details including the Machine Name. I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this, something with lesser API calls perhaps.

Background:

I need to restart a specific instance of a Azure Web app programmatically. Users calling restart can only see the VM name or Role Instance of a web App in Application insights.
I found APIs to list instances but nothing to find mapping between instance Id and VM name directly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try this API [Virtual Machines - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/list)?

By Using this api, you can get id and name from values[]

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2018-06-01
```

Result example ：

```
{
  "value": [
             {
               // ignore

               "id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionsID}/resourceGroups/test-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/my-vmname",
               "name": "my-vmname"
             }
  ]
}
```

Comment: op is asking about web apps, not vms?

Comment: From my understanding, each instance of my Web app will run on a unique VM.I need  the list of those VMs. So I'm looking for an API that takes a web app name and provides a list of instances and the VM name of where that instance is running or provide VM name for a specific instance.

Comment: If your web app's name is webapp , you shoud find instance name webapp-xxxx

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the REST API [`Web Apps - List Instance Identifiers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listinstanceidentifiers) to get all scale-out instances of an app.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/instances?api-version=2016-08-01
```

Actually, the instances for a WebApp by scaling out is for its App Service Plan. For example, I scaled up the instance number of my webapp to 4 on Azure portal, then the instance number of its App Service Plan as the figures below.

[image]

And I got the json response from the REST API, as below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using this API to get the instance ID that you pointed out in the screen shot. Now I need the machine name that each instance is running on. The machine or VM name is something like RD0003FFE7494B.